# Ajax / Jquery & Laravel - Dynamic Dropdown select and fetch the select value to textbox

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel, eloquent

I want to fetch my data in a textbox by selecting a dropdown select on my view. now here's my table I have this table which populate my dropdown named `aircraft_registration_number` and when I select one of its data I need to fetch the number or `aircraft_id` on which row I select and be fetched on the textbox.

So take a look at my table

[image]

and here is my controller

```
public function findPrice(Request $request){
        $p = Aircraft::select('aircraft_id')->where('id',$request->id)->first();
        return response()->json($p);
    }
```

my Route

```
 Route::get('/admin/aircrafts/findPrice', 'Admin\AircraftsController@findPrice');
```

my View

```
{{Form::select('aircraft_registration_number', $aircraft_reg,null,['class' => 'form-control-lg productname', 'placeholder' => 'Select RPC No.'])}}<br>
    <br>
    {{Form::text('prod_price', '', ['class' => 'form-control','data-dependent'=>'city'])}}
```

my AJAX/JQuery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('change','.productname',function(){
            var prod_id=$(this).val();

            var a=$(this).parent();
            console.log(prod_id);
            var op="";

            $.ajax({
            type:'get',
            url:'{!!URL::to('findPrice')!!}',
            data:{'id':prod_id},
            dataType:'json',//return data will be json
            success:function(data){
                console.log("price");
                console.log(data.price);

                // here price is column name in products table data.coln name

                a.find('.prod_price').val(data.price);

            },
            error:function(){

            }
        });


        });
  });

  </script>
```

on my console.logs the error was this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are targeting the wrong URL.

Change this:

```
url:'{!! URL::to('findPrice') !!}',
```

to this:

```
url:'{!! URL::to('admin/aircrafts/findPrice') !!}',
```

Or:

```
url: '{!! url('admin/aircrafts/findPrice') !!}',
```

Edit: To populate your text box, you also need to make sure that you are targeting the right class. Since, in your AJAX callback, you are targeting `.prod_price`, you also need to add the class to your input.

```
{{Form::text('prod_price', '', ['class' => 'form-control prod_price','data-dependent'=>'city'])}}
```

Comment: thanks!!!! the error was gone but the data was not displaying i wonder why.. still the data was being fetch as in id

Comment: I don't understand. You could do a `console.log()` in your AJAX callback to see if you are getting the data correctly and work from there :)

Comment: oh no.. :( please help me sir the only problem now is i cannot display the fetch data in ajax to my textbox :(

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: already tried that sir, but still nothing is being displayed on my textbox do you think there's something wrong with the controller?